# How to write proper algorithem serialize this special format of json data？

Tags: javascript, json

I have a csv file, looks like this:

photoSum,annee,mois

2732,2002,1

1030,2002,2

1661,2002,7

1450,2002,3

1308,2002,4

2131,2002,5

2891,2002,6

2748,2002,8

2140,2002,9

1499,2002,10

1211,2002,11

1398,2002,12

5376,2003,1

2780,2003,2

1927,2003,3

2266,2003,4

3670,2003,5

4071,2003,6

4764,2003,7

5261,2003,8

I want to make this CSV file a json data serialization like this:
**The annual data with monthly Sort**

```
{
        "2002": [
            1, //January
            22, //February
            33,
            44,
            345,
            45,
            232,
            43423,
            324324,
            324324,
            324324,
            6556
        ],
        "2003": [
            3.5,
            4,
            4.3,
            6.6,
            11.7,
            13.2,
            16.2,
            16.5,
            12.7,
            8.4,
            5,
            5.3
        ]
}
```

I am trying to use **Javascript to convert this csv to json**, write many kinds of Regular Expressions, but all failed, i found that i have to consider the sequence of this csv file very carefully, it is too complicated, can somebody **HELP me? PLEASE**

Comment: Show us what have you tried (code)

Comment: I still dont have a good idea...T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function parseCSV(data, rowSeperator) {
    var rows = data.split(rowSeperator || '\n');
    var json = {};
    rows.slice(1).forEach(function (row) {
        var columns = row.split(',');
        var sum = parseInt(columns[0]||0, 10)
        var year = parseInt(columns[1], 10);
        var month = parseInt(columns[2], 10);
        if (year && month) {
            json[year] = json[year] || [];
            json[year][month-1] = sum;
        }
    });
    return json;
}

var json = parseCSV(csvData);
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/qug4thb9/**

Comment: thank you very much! I test the code, it is good. But i have an advice, maybe the second line should be:  var rows = data.toString().split(rowSeperator || '\n');